# Erro javascript if

Tags: javascript, html

Não estou conseguindo fazer uma condição com if por exemplo:

```
asd=true;
if(asd=='true'){
   alert('funcionou');
}
```

mas parece que de alguma forma ele não está entrando no if

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O asd é um valor **boleano** e não pode ser tratado como uma string tente o seguinte:

```
var asd=true;
if(asd==true){
   alert('funcionou');
}
```

ou

```
var asd=true;
if(asd){
   alert('funcionou');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Como já responderam, vou apenas dar uma dica.

Algumas convenções (e.g. PHPCS, pacote pear) nem sequer permitem comparações utilizando duplo igual (==), mas exigem o triplo (===). Por quê?

A comparação de igualdade com == pode ser imprevisível:

```
asd == true // true
asd == 1 // true
asd == 'true' // false
```

Mas com === temos resultados precisos:

```
console.log(asd === true); // true
console.log(asd !== false); // true
console.log(asd === 1); // false
console.log(asd === false); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você atribuir `true` a uma variável, então o mínimo esperado seria que comparando com o mesmo valor original, a condição passasse... mas você usou algo diferente na comparação: `'true'`.

No javascript, `'true'` não é o mesmo que `true`. O primeiro é uma string, ou seja, é um texto, em que está escrita a palavra *true*, o segundo é um valor booleano, com o significado de *verdadeiro*.

**Conclusão:** ao comparar tenha certeza de que o tipo dos objetos sendo comparados é compatível. Se não forem, então possivelmente a comparação vai falhar.

Answer (score 1):

Você está comparando dois tipos de variáveis diferentes.

Mesmo não sendo uma comparação estrita, ela vai falhar pois não são iguais.

- `==` comparação normal, ex: `1 == true // verdadeiro`
- `===` comparação estrita, verifica se o tipo é o mesmo, ex: `1 == true // falso`

O jeito mais simples de você comparar no javascript algo é verdadeiro, é assumindo que ele não é falso. Exemplo:

```
var foo = true;
var bar = false;
if (foo) { /* vai executar pois foo existe e é alguma coisa */ }
if (bar) { /* não vai executar, pois bar é falso */}
```

Você pode testar se algo não é falso usando `!variavel`, isso vai inverter o valor da variável, primeiro o javascript vai converter a variável pra um valor testável (boleano), depois vai inverter o valor do resultado e ai aplicar a condicional.

Valores convertidos pra `false`:

- `false`
- `0`
- `-0`
- `''`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

Valores diferente destes serão convertidos pra `true`.

Quando você quer garantir que uma variavel é exatamente um valor falso ou verdadeiro você deve fazer comparação estrita:

```
var verdadeiro = true;
if (verdadeiro === true) { /* faça algo */ }
```

Ainda é possível restringir que a variável seja um valor especifico, por exemplo:

```
var foo = verdadeiro === true;
```

Isso é, se a variável verdadeiro for qualquer coisa que não `true`, o `foo` vai ser `false`, mesmo sendo objeto ou coisas que possam ser convertidas.

- [Mais detalhes sobre comparações no site MDN (em inglês)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).
- [Mais detalhes sobre conversões de tipos (em inglês)](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/type-conversions)